# Pointing Solr (4.8.1) to a Directory (Windows 7)

Tags: apache, solr, indexing, elasticsearch, information-retrieval

I am setting up a search system for a directory of documents (file types such as: MS Word, PDF, .txt, PowerPoint, etc).

The directory of documents is stored locally on my network.

I have Apache Solr up and running on my machine (administrator pane viewable and accessible from localhost port 8983).

I now need to index the content and titles of the documents in the directory, and make that searchable via my Solr server.

Where do I go next?
---More specifically---

- Is there an open source indexing technology I need to integrate or can Solr index the documents on its own?
- How do I tell Solr to search within this directory specifically? (or
  generally, within a directory on my hard drive / local network)

Comment: Solr will not index on its own. An external process must post documents to Solr. Have a look at Apache Nutch, it is a command-line web crawler, but it can be configured to crawl a local file system as well (see the [FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FAQ#How_do_I_index_my_local_file_system.3F)).

Comment: Thank you! Since doing some more of my own research, I have found Nutch to be the crawler of choice with Solr - though I have not yet configured it.

Comment: As it turns out - the binary solr downloads come with several technologies that allow for manual indexing - using ExtractingRequestHandler and the command line commands java -Dauto -jar post.jar <file name> and
java -Dauto -Drecursive -jar post.jar <folder name>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Solr Cell](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika) (what used to known as the [ExtractingRequestHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler))

It's built on top of the [Apache Tika Project](http://tika.apache.org/).

About Solr Cell:

> **Key Concepts**
>
> When using the Solr Cell framework, it is helpful to keep the
>   following in mind:
>
> - Tika will automatically attempt to determine the input document type    (Word, PDF, HTML) and extract the content appropriately. If
>     you like,    you can explicitly specify a MIME type for Tika with the
>     stream.type    parameter.
> - Tika works by producing an XHTML stream that it feeds to a SAX    ContentHandler. SAX is a common interface implemented for many
>     different XML parsers. For more information, see
>     http://www.saxproject.org/quickstart.html.
> - Solr then responds to Tika's SAX events and creates the fields to    index.
> - Tika produces metadata such as Title, Subject, and Author according    to specifications such as the DublinCore. See
>     http://tika.apache.org/1.5/formats.html for the file types supported.
> - Tika adds all the extracted text to the content field. This field is    defined as "stored" in schema.xml. It is also copied to the text
>     field with a copyField rule.
> - You can map Tika's metadata fields to Solr fields. You can also boost    these fields.
> - You can pass in literals for field values. Literals will override    Tika-parsed values, including fields in the Tika metadata object, the 
>     Tika content field, and any "captured content" fields.
> - You can apply an XPath expression to the Tika XHTML to restrict the    content that is produced.

The wiki page on [Solr Cell](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika) has a tutorial and configuration information.